# Open and edit value in JsonObject

Tags: android, android-file, android-json

I have local Json file in asset folder.

I use this code to open file

```
try {
        is = getAssets().open("data.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();

        jsonString = is.toString();
        jsonString = new String(buffer,"UTF-8");

        myJson = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        jsonArrayData = myJson.getJSONArray("diTich");
        int leng = jsonArrayData.length();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < leng ; i++) {
            mTitle = jsonArrayData.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
            mDescription = jsonArrayData.getJSONObject(i).getString("description");
            mAddress = jsonArrayData.getJSONObject(i).getString("address");
            mStatus = jsonArrayData.getJSONObject(i).getString("status");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My's Json file

> {
>     "ABCD": [
>       {
>         "title": "abcd",
>         "description": "abc",
>         "address": "bnc",
>         "image": "abcg",
>         "status": false
>       }
>     ]
>   }

I retrieved value in JsonObject. Now I wanna edit value in this
For example, change value of key "status" from false to true. 
How can I do this ? I don't know write replace it !

Thanks you guys !

Answer (score 1):

You use the `JSONObject.put()` methods of the JSONObject class. So, in your example you could do this:

```
jsonArrayData.getJSONObject(i).put("status", true);
```

That will clobber the value that is currently there.

Comment: Hi DavidCAdams ! I tried you way but the value don't update ! Do you know another way ?

Comment: It may be because the JSONObject is in a JSONArray. Try this:
    JSONObject newObject jsonArrayData.getJSONObject(i);
    newObject.put("status", true);

If you need the JSONArray changed, then use the JSONArray.put() method to put that new JSONObject into the JSONArray at the index (i).